# Default argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "char *"

Tags: c++

So I got this code from my teacher but it doesn`t work combined with other code, it works only if it is separatly in a project. The whole code works great, less this part

"Notes" is an other class which works perfectly

```
class student
{
    char name[30];
    notes marks;
public:
    student(int = 8, char* =" "); //HERE IS WHERE I GOT THE PROBLEM, AT HIS CHAR*
    ~student();
    void read_name();
    void read_marks();
    void modif_mark(int, double);
    void print();
    void check_marks();
};

/*...
  ...
  ...
*here is a lot of code working great*
  ...
  ...
  ...
*/

student::student(int nr_marks, char* sir) :
    marks(nr_marks)
{
    strcpy_s(name, sir);
}
```

Comment: You are trying to assign `const char *` to a `char *`. The error says that.

Comment: Aside: you have omitted one argument for `errno_t strcpy_s(char *dest, rsize_t dest_size, const char *src);`

Comment: If your professor told you to write code like `student(int = 8, char* =" ");`, I'd really like to meet them one day...

Comment: @NikosC. If you were to set up meetings with every professor who spread poor coding practice, you'd have a full schedule.

Comment: Due to an exception in the rules, string literals used to be assignable to non-`const` pointers but this was a mistake and the exception has been removed from the language. In any case, even when it was allowed, it was a very bad idea.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Oh, that. Yeah, that's unfortunate. But I rather meant the missing parameter identifiers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on compiler, C-style string literals may be allocated in readonly memory. Thus they are `const char[N+1]` *(`N` is the string length)* *(which is implicitly convertible to `const char*` because of array to pointer decay)*.

The problem you're having is that it's illegal to drop `const` qualifiers *(with the exception of the infamous `const_cast` or equivalent C-style cast)*.

Since you're only reading from `sir`, you can fix this by making `sir` be `const char*` instead, which doesn't violate `const`:

```
class student {
...
student(int = 8, const char* =" "); // problem solved
...
};

student::student(int nr_marks, const char* sir) : // remember to change it here as well
    marks(nr_marks)
{
    strcpy(name, sir);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

About [string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal):

> In C, string literals are of type `char[]`, and can be assigned
>   directly to a (non-const) `char*`. C++03 allowed it as well (but
>   deprecated it, as literals are const in C++). C++11 no longer allows
>   such assignments without a cast.

Your teacher is possibly more versed in C or "dated" C++.  As stated above the language (= modern C++) disallows the assignment / initialization of a `char*` from a string literal.

Workarounds:

- Use `char const *` as type for the parameter. That's the reasonable solution when the string is not modified (why would you modify a string literal??)
- **Not recommended**. When you need to write to that pointer: Store (a copy of) the string literal as a (non const) `char[]` and reference that. Issues: thread safety; side effects; why would you want to do this??
- **Better**. If you need to write to / change the string: use `std::string`.

Answer (score 3):

Below is the error version

```
print_results("C = ", c);
```

Below is the Solved Version

```
print_results((char*)"C = ", c);
```