# How to fix this: Argument of type "const char*" is incompatible with the parameter of type "char**

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, compiler-errors, char

I am kinda new to C++, currently studying Computer Engineering. I am having problems with this program. I'm getting an error in the `main()` function:

> argument of type "const char*" is incompatible with the parameter of type "char**"

on this line:

```cpp
loan1.setPersonAndLoan(55000.00, 30, 0.04, "Andres Gomez", "(787)654-3423", "56666",
        "Calle Z #456 Fracc Hidalgo");
```

This is my whole code, if it helps:

Main:

```cpp
#include "Mortgage.h"

int main() {

    Mortgage loan1;
    loan1.setPersonAndLoan(55000.00, 30, 0.04, "Andres Gomez", "(787)654-3423", "56666",
        "Calle L #456 Fracc Hidalgo");
    loan1.displayInfo();
    loan1.displayLoan();
    Mortgage loan2(loan1);
    loan2.displayInfo();
    loan2.displayLoan();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Object File:

```cpp
#include "Mortgage.h"

Mortgage::Mortgage() {
    loan = 3000.0;
    years = 9;
    iRate = 0.09;
    char tempName[20] = "John Doe";
    char tempPhone[20] = "000-000-0000";
    char tempId[20] = "000-00-0000";
    char tempAddress[20] = "Some Place";
    setName(tempName);
    setPhone(tempPhone);
    setId(tempId);
    setAddress(tempAddress);
}
Mortgage::Mortgage(double l, int y, double r, char* n, char* p, char* id1, char* a) {
    setLoan(l);
    setYears(y);
    setIRate(r);
    setName(n);
    setPhone(p);
    setId(id1);
    setAddress(a);
}
//Mortgage::Mortgage(char* n, char* p, char* id1, char* a) {
// setName(n);
// setPhone(p);
// setId(id1);
// setAddress(a);
//}
Mortgage::Mortgage(Mortgage& aMortgage) {
    setLoan(aMortgage.getLoan());
    setYears(aMortgage.getYears());
    setIRate(aMortgage.getIRate());
    setName(aMortgage.getName());
    setPhone(aMortgage.getPhone());
    setId(aMortgage.getId());
    setAddress(aMortgage.getAddress());
}
//==================================================================
Mortgage::~Mortgage() {
    delete[] name;
    delete[] phone;
    delete[] id;
    delete[] address;
}
//================================================================
void Mortgage::setLoan(double l) {
    loan = l;
}
void Mortgage::setYears(int y) {
    years = y;
}
void Mortgage::setIRate(double r) {
    iRate = r; 
}
void Mortgage::setName(char* n) {
    name = new char[strlen(n) + 1];
    strcpy_s(name, strlen(n) + 1, n);
}
void Mortgage::setPhone(char* p) {
    phone = new char[strlen(p) + 1];
    strcpy_s(phone, strlen(p) + 1, p);
}
void Mortgage::setId(char* id1) {
    id = new char[strlen(id1) + 1];
    strcpy_s(id, strlen(id1) + 1, id1);
}
void Mortgage::setAddress(char* a) {
    address = new char[strlen(a) + 1];
    strcpy_s(address, strlen(a) + 1, a);
}
void Mortgage::setPersonAndLoan(double l, int y, double r, char* n, char* p, char* id1, char* a) {
    setLoan(l);
    setYears(y);
    setIRate(r);
    setName(n);
    setPhone(p);
    setId(id1);
    setAddress(a);
}
//=================================================================
double Mortgage::getLoan() const {
    return loan;
}
int Mortgage::getYears() const {
    return years;
}
double Mortgage::getIRate() const {
    return iRate;
}
char* Mortgage::getName() const {
    return name;
}
char* Mortgage::getPhone() const {
    return phone;
}
char* Mortgage::getId() const {
    return id;
}
char* Mortgage::getAddress() const {
    return address;
}
//===================================================================
double Mortgage::getTerm() const {
    double term;
    term = pow((1 + (getIRate() / 100.0) / 12.0), (12 * years));
    return term;
}
double Mortgage::getMonthlyPayment() const {
    double payment;
    payment = (loan * (getIRate() / 100.0) * (getTerm() / 12.0)) / (getTerm() - 1);
    return payment;
}
double Mortgage::getTotalPaid() const {
    double total;
    total = (12 * years * getMonthlyPayment());
    return total;
}
//======================================================================
void Mortgage::displayInfo() const {
    cout << left << setw(20) << getName() << setw(20) << getPhone()
        << setw(30) << getId() << setw(20) << getAddress() << endl;
}
void Mortgage::displayLoan() const {
    cout << left << setw(20) << "\nMonthly Payment" << setw(20) << "Total Payed to Bank"
        << endl;
    cout << left << setw(20) << getMonthlyPayment() << setw(20)
        << getTotalPaid() << endl;
}
```

Header:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class Mortgage {
private:
    double loan, iRate;
    int years;
    char *name,
        *phone,
        *id,
        *address;
public:
    //constructors
    Mortgage();
    Mortgage(double l, int y, double r, char* n, char* p, char* id1, char* a);
    //Mortgage(char*, char*, char* , char*);
    Mortgage(Mortgage &);
    //destructor
    ~Mortgage();
    //setters
    void setLoan(double);
    void setIRate(double);
    void setYears(int);
    void setName(char*);
    void setPhone(char*);
    void setId(char*);
    void setAddress(char*);
    void setPersonAndLoan(double l, int y, double r, char* n, char* p, char* id1, char* a);
    //getters
    double getLoan() const;
    int    getYears() const;
    double getIRate() const;
    char*  getName() const;
    char*  getPhone() const;
    char*  getId() const;
    char*  getAddress() const;

    double getTerm() const;
    double getMonthlyPayment() const;
    double getTotalPaid() const;
    //display
    void displayInfo() const;
    void displayLoan() const;
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Default argument of type "const char \*" is incompatible with parameter of type "char \*"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55751920/default-argument-of-type-const-char-is-incompatible-with-parameter-of-type)

Comment: You need to put in a bit of effort here.  Please read what a [mre] is and then create one.  In doing that, you may solve your own problem anyway.

Comment: `void setPersonAndLoan(double l, int y, double r, char* n, char* p, char* id1, char* a);` all the `char*`s here and other calls should be changed to `const char*` if you want to accept string literals. With that said, looks like you need to change many functions and not just this one. This has been a requirement since 2011 and the c++11 standard.

Comment: The obvious question is -- why are you not using `std::string` instead of `char *`?

Answer (score 0):

Let me help you learn to fish.  Your error:

```
argument of type "const char*" is incompatible with the parameter of type "char**"
```

This is telling you that you have an argument to a function of type "const char*" that you're trying to pass into a function which is expecting a parameter of type "char**".

You mention that it's occurring on this line:

```
loan1.setPersonAndLoan(55000.00, 30, 0.04, "Andres Gomez", "(787)654-3423", "56666",
        "Calle Z #456 Fracc Hidalgo");
```

So I immediately start to suspect any parameters that are of type "const char*" (basically your string literals - they're "const" meaning they can't be changed).

Now I look at your function declaration (the body is unimportant at this point) for setPersonAndLoan:

```
void Mortgage::setPersonAndLoan(double l, int y, double r, char* n, char* p, char* id1, char* a)
```

And you indeed have a bunch of 'char *' parameters, not const char, which is probably why the error is occurring.

That said, the error you posted had "char **" which I'm wondering if it's a typo?