# Not sure why I can't convert from string to int?

Tags: c++, type-conversion

```
string typeVisa (string str);    

int main(){
        string credit_card;
        string type;

        getline(cin, credit_card);
        type = typeVisa(credit_card);
    }

string typeVisa (string str){

    int digit1;
    int digit2;

    digit1 = atoi(str[0]);
    digit2 = atoi(str[1]);
    // code continues and returns a string

}
```

argument of type "char" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *"
What does this mean ^^?

Comment: Does this resource help? It deals with a similar issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55751920/default-argument-of-type-const-char-is-incompatible-with-parameter-of-type

Comment: atoi accepts "const char * ", when you do atoi(str[0]) it passess "char", that's why you are getting this error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to convert each digit separately, you write something like below

```
//Instead of this:
digit1 = atoi(str[0]);
digit2 = atoi(str[1]);

//use this:
digit1 = (int)str[0] - '0';
digit2 = (int)str[1] - '0';
```

PS: you might need add validation for passed string is numeric.

Comment: why are you doing the -48?

Comment: On most but not all computers, `0` is 48.

Comment: @Bellfrank 48 is the ASCII code for `'0'`. Better to use `'0'` instead of a [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).

Comment: @Bellfrank ASCCII value for 0 is 48, you can refer http://www.asciitable.com/ for ascci value of different characters

Comment: Ahh i see, without the 48, I always get the answer +48

Comment: I still don't understand why we have to subtract by 0? is it because strings contain a /0?

Comment: @Bellfrank read [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67747079/65863), I show why '0' is subtracted

Comment: @Bellfrank you need to subtract character '0' & not numeric zero as you want to convert char to string

Answer (score 3):

`atoi()` takes a null-terminated string of characters, but you are trying to pass it a single character instead.  You could do this instead:

```cpp
char arr[] = {str[0], '\0'};
digit1 = atoi(arr);

arr[0] = str[1];
digit2 = atoi(arr);

...
```

But an easier way to convert a `char` in the range `'0'..'9'` to an integer of equivalent value is to subtract `'0'` from the character, thus:

```
'0' - '0' = 48 - 48 = 0
'1' - '0' = 49 - 48 = 1
'2' - '0' = 50 - 48 = 2
And so on...
```

```cpp
digit1 = str[0] - '0';
digit2 = str[1] - '0';
```

Comment: The easiest way is probably `atoi(str.c_str())`

Comment: @MooingDuck That would convert the entire string, which is not what the OP wants